# python total_ordering : why __lt__ and __eq__ instead of __le__?

Tags: python, python-3.x, comparison-operators

In Python3, the [functools.total_ordering decorator](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functools.html#functools.total_ordering) allows one to only overload `__lt__` and `__eq__` to get all 6 comparison operators.

I don't get why one has to write two operators when one would be enough, namely `__le__` or `__ge__`, and all others would be defined accordingly :

```
a < b   <=>   not (b <= a)
a > b   <=>   not (a <= b)
a == b   <=>   (a <= b) and (b <= a)
a != b   <=>   (a <= b) xor (b <= a)
```

Is that just because xor operator does not exists natively?

Comment: `xor` does exist natively.

Comment: @MartijnPieters only bitwise xor, isn't it?

Comment: Bitwise xor is boolean xor for all intents and purposes, both in Python and also in many other languages. In Python `bool` is a subclass of `int`, `False == 0` and `True == 1`. So `True ^ False` and so on work just fine.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The documentation states you **must** define one of `__lt__()`, `__le__()`, `__gt__()`, or `__ge__()`, but only **should** supply an `__eq__()` method.

In other words, the `__eq__` method is *optional*.

The [`total_ordering` implementation](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/ff6a021c25ef9147b8a4c8b3458a085a67959e01/Lib/functools.py#L80-L199) does not require you to specify an `__eq__` method; it only tests for the `__lt__()`, `__le__()`, `__gt__()`, or `__ge__()` methods. It supplies up to 3 missing special methods based of one of those 4.

You can't base the order on *just* `__le__` or `__ge__` because you can't assume that you can swap `a` and `b`; if `b` is a different type `b.__le__` might not be implemented and so your `a < b   <=>   not (b <= a)` map can't be guaranteed. The implementation uses `(a <= b) and (a != b)` if `__le__` is not defined but `__lt__` has been.

The full table of mappings is:

| comparison | available | alternative |
| --- | --- | --- |
| `a > b` | `a < b` | `(not a < b) and (a != b)` |
|  | `a <= b` | `(not a <= b)` |
|  | `a >= b` | `(a >= b) and (a != b)` |
| `a <= b` | `a < b` | `(a < b) or (a == b)` |
|  | `a > b` | `(not a > b)` |
|  | `a >= b` | `(not a >= b) or (a == b)` |
| `a < b` | `a <= b` | `(a <= b) and (a != b)` |
|  | `a > b` | `(not a > b) and (a != b)` |
|  | `a >= b` | `(not a >= b)` |
| `a >= b` | `a < b` | `(not a < b)` |
|  | `a <= b` | `(not a <= b) or (a == b)` |
|  | `a > b` | `(a > b) or (a == b)` |

The `__eq__` method is optional because the base `object` object defines one for you; two instances are considered equal only if they are the same object; `ob1 == ob2` only if `ob1 is ob2` is `True`. See the [`do_richcompare()` function in `object.c`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/ff6a021c25ef9147b8a4c8b3458a085a67959e01/Objects/object.c#L684-L702); remember that the `==` operator in the code there is comparing pointers.

Comment: Is there a way to indicate to to `total_ordering` (or another method) that you only want comparison to work between objects of the same type, so you can deduce that `a < b` implies `b < a` is also available, and then deduce all 6 comparison operator from just one supplied operator implementation?

Comment: @dylanmorroll: read my answer carefully, it explains that it does what you want already: *The total_ordering implementation [...] tests for the `__lt__()`, `__le__()`, `__gt__()`, or `__ge__()` methods. **It supplies up to 3 missing special methods based of one of those 4.*** There are only 5 comparison methods, not six, by the way.

Comment: @dylanmorroll: you can return `NotImplemented` from your `__lt__` implementation if the comparison is against a different type you don't support, and total_ordering will do the right thing.

Comment: Perhaps I should have clarified, I meant to get all the comparison operators including a proper equality (rather than the implicit equality which is an identity check). Ah yes I was including not equal to in my counting of 6 but I guess negation isn't a new operator.

Comment: @dylanmorroll then provide an `__eq__` implantation and make use of the `NotImplemented` signalling object.