# Override all Python comparison methods in one declaration

Tags: python

Suppose you have a simple class like `A` below. The comparison methods are all virtually the same except for the comparison itself. Is there a shortcut around declaring the six methods in one method such that all comparisons are supported, something like `B`?

I ask mainly because `B` seems more Pythonic to me and I am surprised that my searching didn't find such a route.

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, number: float, metadata: str):
        self.number = number
        self.metadata = metadata

    def __lt__(self, other):
        return self.number < other.number

    def __le__(self, other):
        return self.number <= other.number

    def __gt__(self, other):
        return self.number > other.number

    def __ge__(self, other):
        return self.number >= other.number

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self.number == other.number

    def __ne__(self, other):
        return self.number != other.number


class B:
    def __init__(self, number: float, metadata: str):
        self.number = number
        self.metadata = metadata

    def __compare__(self, other, comparison):
        return self.number.__compare__(other.number, comparison)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `functools` module provides the `total_ordering` decorator which is meant to provide all comparison methods, given that you provide at least one from `__lt__()`, `__le__()`, `__gt__()`, or `__ge__()`.

See this answer from [Martijn Pieters](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16238370/2531279).

Comment: Not true. For example, if you only provide `__lt__`, then `A(0, '') <= A(0, '')` still returns `False`.

Answer (score 0):

To do it easier, python standard library ships with a module named `operator`.

It has the methods like `operator.__eq__` or `operator.__ge__` and so on. So if you want to compare you can easily call them like methods and compare.